# image reference is fixed to the viewport ,it can not be rotated,scaled,moved

Tags: image

when i add an empty image or image/reference then the image appears in the center of viewport out of the empty frame.
the image is fixed to the viewport but the empty frame can be used,scaled,rotated,moved....
something like that
thank you for your comments[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file with the image packed into it via File > External Data > Pack Resources. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.